# C++ Function pointer map with Class Member Variables

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a stl map with key as "KEYWORD" and value as "Class member function" But it is not getting compiled. 
Following is the code. Can anybody please let me know what is wrong. The class member functions are not static.

```
typedef void (RemoteHostManager::*CmdHandlerPtr)(char *);
typedef std::map<char *,CmdHandlerPtr> CommandHandlerSet;
typedef std::map<char *,CmdHandlerPtr>::iterator CommandHandlerSetItr;

void RemoteHostManager::InitializeCmdHandlerMap()
{
    m_CommandSet["HELP"]    = &RemoteHostManager::usage;
    m_CommandSet["CONNECT"] = &RemoteHostManager::Connect;
    m_CommandSet["READ"]    = &RemoteHostManager::Read;
    m_CommandSet["WRITE"]   = &RemoteHostManager::Write;
    m_CommandSet["STOP"]    = &RemoteHostManager::Stop;
    m_CommandSet["START"]   = &RemoteHostManager::Start;
}
```

Following are the errors:

```
RemoteHostManager.cpp: In member function `void
   RemoteHostManager::InitializeCmdHandlerMap()':
RemoteHostManager.cpp:14: no match for `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const
   std::string, void (RemoteHostManager::*)(char*)>, std::pair<const
   std::string, void (RemoteHostManager::*)(char*)>&, std::pair<const
   std::string, void (RemoteHostManager::*)(char*)>*>& [const char[5]]'
   operator
//similar error for other assignments!
```

Comment: the problem is it is getting compiler or it is NOT getting compiled?

Comment: @Avinash : what is the type of `m_CommandSet`?.. and tell us line number corresponds to which piece of code.. by the way, have you changed `char*` to `std::string` in the map?

Comment: So, what's `m_CommandSet`? You posted a bunch of typedef's, yet the most important part - the declaration of `m_CommandSet` - is missing.

Comment: @Avinash : I guess, the type of `m_CommandSet` is not `CommandHandlerSet`; it's rather `CommandHandlerSetItr`.Am I right?

Comment: @Nawaz and @AndreyT, you got it right, my m_commandSet was wrong.

Comment: @Avinash : See I told you. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef std::map<char *,CmdHandlerPtr> CommandHandlerSet;
typedef std::map<char *,CmdHandlerPtr>::iterator CommandHandlerSetItr;
```

First make it `const char*`, or even better `std::string`:

```
typedef std::map<std::string,CmdHandlerPtr> CommandHandlerSet;
typedef std::map<std::string,CmdHandlerPtr>::iterator CommandHandlerSetItr;
```

Note all your member functions should match the type of `CmdHandlerPtr`. That is, the parameter type must be `char*` , and return type must be `void`.

When using the map, you need an instance of type `RemoteHostManager`:

```
RemoteHostManager instance;
string key;
//...
(instance.*m_CommandSet[key])(param);
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am getting error at line  m_CommandSet["HELP"]    = &RemoteHostManager::usage;
and usage memeber function is defined as void RemoteHostManager::usage( char *inCmd)

Answer (score 1):

If class member functions are not static, you need to bind the method with an instance when setting it in the map. You could use boost::bind to do so.

Comment: What? Not with the syntax he's using. Also that would change the program from what he wants to do. Please read up on pointer-to-member-function variables.

Comment: On which instance will it call the method then if the methods aren't static ?